# R: count elements in column and combine without loop/rearrange

Tags: r, dataframe, count, col

to summarize my problem i got a dataframe like:

```
1   10
3   20
5   40
6   30 
1   100
2   25
7   13
3   70
```

Like for an ID in the 1st and a price in the 2nd column. I need an output like:

```
1   110
3   90
5   40
6   30 
1   110
2   25
7   13
3   90
```

So the sum of all prices with same ID without any loops, without rearranging or compressing.
I don't want solutions like:

```
1  110
2  25
3  90
5  40
6  30
7  13
```

And this one is also not helpful:

```
 for(i in 1:8){
   x=0
   for(j in 1:8){
     if(df[i,1]==df[j,1]){x=x+df[j,2]}}
   df[i,3]=x
 }
df[,2]=df[,3]
```

cause it only works for small dataframes (df).

I guess the solution is simple... but anyhow I could not make it..

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You want to group by ID and then sum price for each group?

Comment: The order of ID should be same and not be compressed & the Price should be combined each time the ID is the same in the 1st column..

Comment: Then use `mutate` instead of `summarize`. It will work the same when grouped, but will keep the same number of rows instead of summarizing by group.

Comment: Try `df1$V2 <- with(df1, ave(V2, V1, FUN = sum))`

Comment: Thank you very much,markus solution totally works!